# performance counter events associated with false sharing

Tags: multithreading, performance, caching, performancecounter, false-sharing

I am looking at the performance of OpenMP program, specifically cache and memory performance.
I have found guidelines while back ago how to analyze performance with Vtune that mentioned which counters to watch out for. However now cannot seem to find the manual.

If you know which manual I have in question or if you know the counters/events, please let me know. Also if you have other techniques for analyzing multithreaded memory performance, please share if you can

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [article discussion this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx).

The most common counters to examine are L2 cache misses and branch prediction misses.

Note that, in VS2010, you can use the concurrency visualizer in the new profiling tools to directly see this.  It does a great job of helping you analyze this information, including directly showing you how your code lays out, showing you misses, blocks, and many other useful tools for debugging and profiling concurrent apps.

Comment: thanks, I use Linux for development/deployment but i can parse out hardware stuff from the article.

Comment: Yeah - the same info should work.  Intel has some commerical offerings to help with this, as well...

Comment: I have been using vtune, but not for concurrency profiling. VT is free for noncommercial.  they have thread analyzer as well, but I do not have it yet

Comment: do you know if Visual Studio profiler has capability to collect data on remote UNIX, and display locally? Linux offerings seem to be lacking as far as the visualization is concerned in OpenMP domain